# Save UISwitch's toggled data in UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I've declared a boolean with default value `true`, if my `UISwitch` is on I want boolean variable to be true else false, my code works fine until I try to store that boolean in `UserDefaults` when I reset the xCode Simulator I check with `print` method but it is not really saved...
any solution will be appericated.

```swift
    var userDefaultSamarxvo:Bool = true
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        defaults.set(userDefaultSamarxvo,forKey: "Samarxvo")   // set of userdefault
        if userDefaultSamarxvo {
            print("hello")
        }else{
            print("olleh")
        }
    }
    @IBAction func samarxvoDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn {
            userDefaultSamarxvo.toggle()
            print("samarxo")
        }else{
            userDefaultSamarxvo.toggle()
            print("samarxo 1 ")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense really, what is `userDefaultVeganuri`? Where does that variable come from and how does it relate to `userDefaultSamarxvo`? And why are you writing to USerDefaults in viewDidLoad?

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` you want to load the saved value *from* user defaults.  When the switch changes you need to save the new value *to* user defaults.  Setting a local variable (`userDefaultSamarxvo`) doesn't change what is stored in the user defaults; Local variables don't bind to user defaults storage

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `userDefaultVeganuri` was just a typo sorry fixed

Comment: Well you doing things in the wrong way, see the comment from @Paulw11 above for a proper solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` you want to load the saved value *from* user defaults.  When the switch changes you need to save the new value *to* user defaults.

Setting a local variable (`userDefaultSamarxvo`) doesn't change what is stored in the user defaults; Local variables don't bind to user defaults storage.

There is an added complication; `bool(forKey)` will return `false` if there is no value for the key in UserDefaults.  If you want the initial value to be `true` then you need to handle that in some way.  You can use `object(forKey)` which returns an optional

```
var userDefaultSamarxvo:Bool = true {
   didSet {
       UserDefaults.standard.set(userDefaultSamarxvo, forKey:switchKey)
   }
}
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let switchKey = "Samarxvo"

@IBOutlet weak var theSwitch: UISwitch!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if defaults.object(forKey: switchKey) != nil {
        userDefaultSamarxvo = defaults.bool(forKey: switchKey)
    }

    self.theSwitch.isOn = userDefaultSamarxvo
}

    
@IBAction func samarxvoDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    userDefaultSamarxvo = sender.isOn        
}
```

I have used a `didSet` clause to update the user defaults value when the property changes.